# Playで編集時にDBの値を空にするには

Tags: scala, playframework

playframework(2.5.6)で以下のようなフォームの入力を作っています。

```
case class User(age: Option[Int])

val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "age" -> optional(number)
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
println(form.bindFromRequest().value)
```

フォーム編集時に空文字が送られてきたらDBの値をNULLにしたいんですが、Option[Int]の場合、空が送られてきたかどうか判断できません。
例えば、

- ?age=20 : Some(20)
- ?age= : None
- なし : None

となってしまうので、DB更新時に送られてきてないのか、それとも空にしたいのか分かりません、、、。
どうするのが良いでしょうか。詳しい方教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

PlayのForm周りは詳しくありませんが回答します。

`form.bindFromRequest`は`implicit request`のbodyからデータをbindします。

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.6/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L76-L88

つまり、`request.body`に`age`をキーとするデータが含まれているかどうかで判別可能かと思います。

BodyParserが未指定の場合、`request.body`の型は`AnyContent`になっていて判別が面倒です。
下記のように`BodyParsers.parse.urlFormEncoded`を指定してMapとして取得できるようにします。

```
def addUser = Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.urlFormEncoded) { implicit request =>
  form.bindFromRequest().fold(
    errorForm => {
      // error
    },
    user => {
      if (request.body.contains("age")) {
        // form から"age"が送信されてきた

      } else {

      }
    }
  )
}

case class User(age: Option[Int])

val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "age" -> optional(number)
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

Comment: やはりスマートな解決は難しそうですよね。なにか空であることが分かるようにするしかないですかね。型安全がゆえに不便ですね、、。